# Are NSManagedObject's retain cycles still possible?

Tags: ios, core-data

According to the documentation there is something we have to bother about: memory leaks. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMemory.html:

> **Breaking Relationship Strong Reference Cycles**
>
> When you have relationships between managed objects, each object
>   maintains a strong reference to the object or objects to which it is
>   related. This can cause strong reference cycles. To ensure that
>   reference cycles are broken, when you're finished with an object you
>   can use the managed object context method refreshObject:mergeChanges:
>   to turn it into a fault.
>
> You typically use refreshObject:mergeChanges: to refresh a managed
>   object’s property values. If the mergeChanges flag is YES, the method
>   merges the object’s property values with those of the object available
>   in the persistent store coordinator. If the flag is NO, however, the
>   method simply turns an object back into a fault without merging, which
>   causes it to break strong references to related managed objects. This
>   breaks the strong reference cycle between that managed object and the
>   other managed objects.
>
> Note that, of course, before a managed object can be deallocated there
>   must be no strong references to it, including from outside of Core
>   Data. See also Change and Undo Management.

But. There are not any Apple's code examples where this problem is solved.
I've checked the TopSongs, iPhoneCoreDataRecipes, CoreDataBooks, ThreadedCoreData sample projects, but none of them has respect to this problem. Does it mean that object relationships are weak now a days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object relationships are not weak.  However we are now using ARC for everything and it knows how to handle these reference cycles properly.

NOTE: That documentation is old and I suggest reading the updated guide.

Comment: I see this in the bottom of the page `Updated: 2014-07-15`. Looks pretty fresh to contain ARC-related updates. Any ideas where to get the right guide?

Comment: That is the older guide.  It was updated with the releases at WWDC and is a part of those betas.  If you grab the latest beta of Xcode you will find the updated guide attached to it.

Comment: I have trouble believing that Core Data breaks retain cycles for us. Can you explain how it knows when to deallocate two objects when they both have references to each other? (i.e. with relationships)

Comment: I am not privy to the internals of Core Data (I have asked many times) but I can tell you that this documentation is very old, pre-dates ARC, and that internal retain cycles with regard to relationships have not been an issue for a very long time.  If memory serves, that part of the guide is from the original document written around 2004.

Comment: Okay, I am not aware about "internal retain cycles" so we may just be talking about different things.

Answer (score 2):

Relationships are not `weak` and nothing in the new documentation says anything about Core Data being safe from retain cycles. In fact the first paragraph under ["Turning Object into Faults"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH18-SW1) specifically mentions about strong reference cycles:

*Turning a realized object into a fault can be useful in pruning the object graph, as well as ensuring that property values are current. Turning a managed object into a fault releases unnecessary memory, sets its in-memory property values to nil, and breaks strong references to related objects. (see Reducing Memory Overhead and Ensuring Data Is Up to Date)*

Comment: Considering the entire section on reference cycles was removed I strongly suspect that blurb is an oversight in the edit.  I filed a radar for clarification.  Core Data is not safe from retain cycles, never has been, never will be.  It is now safe from **internal** retain cycles which is what that section of the original documentation was about.

Comment: @Marcus As I started using CoreData when ARC came around, I am not aware of these *internal* retain cycles. But wouldn't there be no way for CoreData to clean-up property-level retain cycles before `refreshObject:` or `reset:`? They may have changed the documentation the way it is now to indicate that we still need to handle these cases. Thanks for filing a radar by the way! I'd love to hear their answer as well.

Comment: There is no way for Core Data to clean up property level retain cycles that are external to Core Data.  There is no way for the compiler to do it under ARC either.  If you have two strong retains pointing at each other those objects will remain in memory until the app dies.  That is just bad code and nothing that the libraries can fix.  This bit of documentation was referring to retain cycles between two `NSManagedObject` instances that was a problem when Core Data was first released.